# model viewmodel dictionary value null after adding in controller

Tags: c#, dictionary, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model for person that has dictionary to hold Gender values (the values are added in a controller). I have created a viewmodel with person class and other properties. In controller I tried to add values to dictionary in person class through an instance of viewmodel. It does not throw an error but the dictionary value is always null. The code works if I do not use viewmodel and work with model directly. Important!!!! (I have to add values to dictionary via controller) Thanks for your help. Please code below.
In Model:

```
public class dictionary
{
    [Display(Name ="Dictionary Dropdownlist")]
    public Dictionary<string,string> dpdnDict { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
public class dictionaryviewmodel
{
    public dictionary dictInViewModel {
        get { return new dictionary(); }
        set { }
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(dictionaryviewmodel dictViewModel)
    {
        dictViewModel.dictInViewModel.dpdnDict.Add("M", "Male");
        dictViewModel.dictInViewModel.dpdnDict.Add("F", "Female");
        return View(dictViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this code is indeed throwing an exception on this line

```
dictViewModel.dictInViewModel.dpdnDict.Add("M", "Male");
```

because `dictViewModel.dictInViewModel` returns `new dictionary()` and `dictViewModel.dictInViewModel.dpdnDict` is `null` because `dpdnDict` isn't set anywhere in code. If you want to make this code work change your classes

```
public class dictionaryviewmodel
{
    public class dictionaryviewmodel
    {
        //this getter will create dictionary instance only once
        //and will always return the same instance with previously added values
        //also it instantiates dpdnDict object
        public dictionary dictInViewModel { get; } = new dictionary()
        {
            dpdnDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        };
    }
}
```

And I don't think you pass any data into controller on request so I'd update controller as well

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    dictionaryviewmodel dictViewModel = new dictionaryviewmodel();
    dictViewModel.dictInViewModel.dpdnDict.Add("M", "Male");
    dictViewModel.dictInViewModel.dpdnDict.Add("F", "Female");
    return View(dictViewModel);
}
```